# is operator and == operator

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators

`num1` and `num2` both are 3.5 and `num1 == num2` gives `True`, but for `is` operator it is `False`.

Look at the below code,

Input:

```
num1 = 3.5
num2 = float(input('num2:'))  # num2 stands for 2nd number
print(num1 == num2)
print(num1 is num2)
```

Output:

```
num2:3.5
True
False
```

> `num1` and `num2` both are 3.5 and `num1 == num2` gives `True`, but
>   for `is` operator it is `False`.

Why is `id(num1) != id(num2)` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is

Comment: Closed too quickly - it isn't a pure duplicate of that, though it is closely related.  I was halfway through writing an answer about how integers and floats differ in python, which is why we get this behaviour with floating point values and not integers.

Comment: @Baldrickk it is still a duplicate - the reason why it doesn't _always_ work the same for ints _in CPython_ is explained in the accepted answer of the dup.

Answer (score 1):

Briefly speaking, `is` will check for identity, while `==` will check for equality. The `is` operator compares the identity of two objects, while the `==` operator compares the values of two objects.

Comment: Why is num1 and num2 referring different addresses if both are 3.5?

Comment: @Kaushik, I think that the fact you are using floats could the reason. I tried the same code with integers both variables return the same id.

Comment: Yes, even I tried it and it produced True for both. But why is it False for is when we use float?

Comment: @Kaushik the CPython implementation use internal caching on some immutable objects (notably small integers -  for a definition of "small" that already changed a lot since the 1.5.x days - and literal strings that match python identifier syntax). __This is an implementation detail__. Nothing in the Python language definition mandates that this caching should or shouldn't happen, all it states is that `is` compares the ids of objects (_not_ their "memory location" - the fact that CPython uses memory address as id is also is an implementation detail).

Answer (score 1):

The `==` operator compares the values of both the operands and checks for value equality. Whereas `is` operator checks whether both the operands refer to the same object or not.

Comment: Why is num1 and num2 referring different addresses if both are 3.5?

Answer (score 1):

Like the other two said, == checks equality, is checks id(). Play around with id() to see what the object id's are, they won't be the same which is why 'is' comes back false.